# Android in app billing - where to place the bind code

Tags: android

I am going through this tutorial they have: developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html

and I am in this section "Binding to the MarketBillingService"

They give those code snippets there:

```
try {
  boolean bindResult = mContext.bindService(
    new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.MarketBillingService.BIND"), this,
    Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
  if (bindResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service bind successful.");
  } else {
    Log.e(TAG, "Could not bind to the MarketBillingService.");
  }
} catch (SecurityException e) {
  Log.e(TAG, "Security exception: " + e);
}
```

but I have no idea where to put them. Does it go in the Activity screen where the user presses the "buy" button? If so, what is the mContext object that they use? How do I unstantiate that? Is that like a button listener? Is this code meant to be in a button listener?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put bindService code in the place where you want your app to start the Service, or to bind to the service. Typically, this would be in the onCreate or onStart of every Activity that interacts with the service. In this case, you put the code in the onCreate or onStart of the activity that has the "buy" button. I guess you could even put it in an async task that is started by the button.

Comment: thanks, the thing I am confused about is what is the mContext variable there. Where does that come from?

Comment: mContext is a context. If you bind to a service in your Activity, you can use "this" for context, or "getBaseContext()", or any context you like to use. Please read the android reference documentation on Activities and contexts.

Comment: well doing that gave me a syntax error like this: The method bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int) in the type Context is not applicable for the arguments (Intent, ExtraHelpActivity, int)

Comment: I was doing this: this.getBaseContext().bindService(  and getBaseContext().bindService without the this.  but both seemed not right.

Comment: @Genadinik how u fixed the problem... i got same error msg as u.